# Solution to exponential function in natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

I was wondering if there exists a pair of natural numbers $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $e^n = m$? Of course excluding the simple solution (0,1).

Intuitively, I would say no. However, I am far from finding an argument, nor knowing which theory even treats these types of questions.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There does not. Remember $e$ is a transcendental number which means it is not the root of any polynomial. In particular if $e^n=m$ was an integer then $e$ would be a root of the polynomial $x^n-m=0$.